# UINavigationController donesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

Code:

```
UINavigationController * childNaviVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.subVC];
[self addChildViewController:childNaviVC];
[self.view addSubview:childNaviVC.view];
[childNaviVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
self.subVC.view.frame = childNaviVC.view.frame;
[childNaviVC.view addSubview:self.subVC.view];
[childNaviVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

what i want to do is add a `UINavigationController` (childNaviVC) as sub viewcontroller (subVC) of the designated VC, and use the `UINavigationController`'s root viewController to display the content;
the problem which i met is `UINavigationController`'s root view(subVC) size is consistent with `UINavigationController`'s parent VC

the red view  size isn't equal to the cyan
[image]

thanks

Comment: I just want to display childrenVC‘s navigationbar

Comment: reset frame in viewwillappear function doesn't work

Comment: Is the offset of size of the Navigation Bar?

Comment: Can you show what kind of Output you are expecting ? any sample screen shot ?

Comment: the red view ‘s bottom is equal to the cyan view

Comment: Shortly: you should not do this.

Comment: why do you have the line `self.subVC.view.frame = childNaviVC.view.frame;`? the navigation controller should manage its child view, did you see that it wasn't?  Also if that was the case you should be setting the frame to the superView's bounds.

Comment: I have tried to set the `childNaviVC`  frame , but it doesn't work

Comment: It would help if your example code said which view was which color. (and if you included the code all the way up to the UIWindow instead of just these few view controllers)

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you are double adding the subview's view. The addSubView for the subVC will be breaking the auto layout constraints within your navigation controller.

Change your calls to match the following and see what results you get:

```
UINavigationController * childNaviVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.subVC];
[self addChildViewController:childNaviVC];
[self.view addSubview:childNaviVC.view];
[childNaviVC.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[childNaviVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the function `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to children VC ,and it worked.
    -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

```
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
```

Comment: may i know in which controller `viewDidLayoutSubviews` class you have to write this frame setting ?

Comment: it is `self.subVC`

Comment: it is real work